# JIRA Tempo Plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, jira, tempo

I'm trying to use the API for JIRA's Tempo :

https://tempoplugin.jira.com/wiki/display/TEMPO/Tempo+Servlet+Manual#TempoServletManual-WorklogReport

specifically trying to get worklogs through the url:

http(s)://yourserver.yourdomain/plugins/servlet/tempo-getWorklog/?dateFrom=2011-01-01&dateTo=2011-01-31&format=xml&diffOnly=false&tempoApiToken=my-token

What should be the values for yourserver and yourdomain. if im testing on a localhost, is it 'localhost:port'? or is it the actual url for my account on jira, example: 'jira.companyname.com'? I'm using RestClient to make the request in my app.

Answer (score 0):

It will be actual url for your account on jira. eg -

https://companyname.jira.com/plugins/servlet/tempo-getWorklog/?dateFrom=2014-04-21&dateTo=2014-04-27&format=xml&tempoApiToken=e4cd79c4-0457-42f3-bf29-6f3f0f5c8bcf&projectKey=project&addUserDetails=true&addIssueDetails=true&addWorklogDetails=true&addIssueSummary=true&addIssueDescription=false

The above url returns the result in xml format. Change the appended parameters according to your need. Make sure you enter the right tempoApiToken value (tempo administrator has this value).